# Capturing byte[] return value from GetMethod(methodname).Invoke

Tags: c#, reflection

I am calling a function from a .NET assembly which returns a `byte[]`.

How do I capture the return value of that function ?

I tried doing this

```
byte[] byteData = (byte[])obj.GetType().GetMethod("methodname").Invoke(obj, new object[] { buffer });
```

but I get a `null` value back in `byteData`.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Have you debugged this and checked that you actually step into the target method?

Answer (score 4):

If it's genuinely returning a non-null byte array, that should be absolutely fine.

Are you sure it isn't filling the buffer you've provided, instead of returning a new byte array?

Here's a demo of it working:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    public byte[] GiveMeBytes()
    {
        return new byte[2];
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        object obj = new Test();
        byte[] byteData = (byte[])obj.GetType().GetMethod("GiveMeBytes")
                                     .Invoke(obj, new object[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(byteData.Length); // Prints 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon .. Yes that's what I thought .. I might be doing something else wrong .. I will do a little bit more digging